# Getting "Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string" when trying to insert data to db

Tags: php, database, oop, pdo

I just don't know why i am getting this err. Expert please help me out. I googled and seen very similar type of problem in SO also but I couldn't figure out what actually wrong in my code -- I became helpless here.

My code snippest is given below :

Database:

```
class Database extends PDO
{
    function __construct($dbtype,$dbhost,$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpass)
    {
        parent::__construct($dbtype.':host='.$dbhost.";dbname=".$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpass);
    }
}
```

Model :

```
<?php

/**
* Base Model Class
*/
class Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database(DB_TYPE,DB_HOST,DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

/**
* Auth Controller
*/
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->view->render('registration');
    }

    public function registration()
    {
        $data = array();

        $data['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        $data['email'] = $_POST['email'];
        $data['contact'] = $_POST['contact'];
        $data['password'] = Hash::create('md5', $_POST['password'], HASH_PASSWORD_KEY);

        $this->model->registration($data);
    }

}
```

Registration Model :

```
class Registration extends Model
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function registration($data)
    {
        $sql = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, contact ,password) VALUES (:username, :email, :contact, :password)");
        $sql->execute(array(
            ':username' => $data['username'],
            ':email' => $data['email'],
            ':contact' => $data['contact'],
            ':password' => $data['password']
            ));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should talk about what you have tried to do to fix the error in the question. Also, you might consider moving the error into the body of the question and having a more succinct title.

Comment: I am not seen your connection variable inside your `registration` function

Comment: You tagged pdo but are you sure you aren't using MySQLI because MySQLI doesn't support named placeholders.

Comment: When echo the prepare() statement I got the error. I dont have any idea why i am getting this error . @JamesMatta

Comment: Yes I am not using mysqli , using PDO

Comment: I mentioned the necessary code blocks.. pls help me out

Comment: You can't _echo the prepare() statement_.  It returns a  `PDOStatement object`.